# nextFrame(); that doesn't stop at the next frame

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this scenario when a ball is dropped into a bucket full of water. The bucket have 4 levels of water that are arranged in 4  frames nested inside the bucket. Using the `hitTestObject` I was hopping  that each time the ball fall through the water, the water level in the bucket will drop one level. But instead, it turns out that as long as the ball continue its way down, it will trigger the `nextFrame` and so it wont stop on the next frame but rather go through all frames. Any solution?

```
if (yesh8gBall21.hitTestObject(yesh8allBuckets1)) {
  yesh8allBuckets1.nextFrame();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one seems to work. the code was inside an event handler/listener and I just needed to remove the listener at the proper time.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
stop();

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler1);
function mouseDownHandler1(event: MouseEvent): void {
    yesh8gBall21.gotoAndPlay(1);
}

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handle8Collision2);

function handle8Collision2(evt: Event): void {

    if (yesh8gBall21.hitTestObject(yesh8allBuckets1)) {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handle8Collision2);
        yesh8allBuckets1.nextFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: If all you use the enter frame handler for is that one collision check, then this is the more efficient solution (no sense to continue checking every frame once your condition has been met)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the ball a property inWater and set it  to false on launch.

```
if (yesh8gBall21.hitTestObject(yesh8allBuckets1) && !yesh8gBall21.inWater) {
  yesh8gBall21.inWater = true;
  yesh8allBuckets1.nextFrame();
}
```

Comment: Did that and nothing happened, not even go to the next level. forgive my rookie question. did I have to do something else other than just copy and past to replace my code with yours?

Comment: If this code doesnt go to the nextframe,  (yesh8gBall21.inWater == false) doesnt return true. My AS3 is a little rusty and i do not have a compiler ready, but you might need to declare inWater = false on init of the ball. Tracing its value helps too.

Comment: `false` and `undefined` are not the same thing, that is the problem with this answer.  until you set `yesh8gBall21.inWater` to some value, it is `undefined` and so `yesh8gBall21.inWater == false` will be `false` - use `!yesh8gBall21.inWater` instead.    Though if you set the value to false before hand (as you mention at the start of your answer) it should work as is